# Linker setting for distributed dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, dylib

I'm struggling with the right options in XCode to include a dylib in my app. I do have a dylib in `/usr/local/lib` which I do need for my app. As long as I set this path in Lib Search Paths

[image]

everything works fine. But of course I want to distribute the dylib with my app which is why I added it to a copy phase:

[image]

This indeed copies the dylib into the `Frameworks` folder in the app. But running on the target system, the app does not find the dylib. It even does not find it in `/usr/local/lib`. Rather it croaks:

> Dyld Error Message:
>
> Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib

So, which option needs to be set?

**Edit** I put together a sample project [here](http://liquit.biz/Archive.zip). It contains 3 zips: one project, one with the headers to be placed in `/usr/local/include` and one with the dylibs to be placed in `/usr/local/lib`. Once the app is compiled it should be able to run anywhere. The dylib is copied into the app, but when run on a clean machine it still looks in `/usr/local/lib` for the dylib.

I tried (too) many ways to get this to work, so I'm currently completely mixed up.

Comment: Do you have the `dylib` included under `Link Binary with Libraries` in Build Phases? I would also recommend making a copy of the `dylib` and adding it to your project in the `Frameworks` folder, that way it is setup properly when you build your project.

Comment: @l'L'l  Yes, sure. Else the compile would already fail. Copy to project does make no difference. The dylib needs to be inside the app which is done with the above copy phase.

Comment: Try adding `@executable_path/Frameworks` to Build Settings > Linking > Runpath Search Paths.

Comment: @l'L'l  It had been `@executable_path/../Frameworks` but changing it did not help.

Comment: Another question, have you cleaned your project? It should've worked otherwise. The path showing for your `dylib` does not look correct in the `Copy Files` image you have either. It should look like this: `...in Frameworks`.

Comment: One more observation: Look at the error message `Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib`, now look at the name of your dylib `libopencv_imgproc.3.2.0.dylib`, notice the missing `0`.

Comment: @l'L'l Looks promising. Been away for a moment and now it's time to sleep. I'll check that tomorrow :)

Comment: @l'L'l Couldn't wait... Had cleaned (also derived data), no change. I created a copy of the culprit in the app with the right name. Verified that they are correct libs with `nm`. Still it croaks the it does not find it. Now - time for some sleep! (Found also this to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117128/xcode-dylib-looking-in-usr-lib?rq=1

Comment: @l'L'l I gave up. There does not seem to be a way to add a search path that finds dylibs in the app package. It expects them in a fixed system location :-( I'll create an extra distro to place the needed libs. Can't believe that I'm the only one needing that :-/

Comment: If you put a small Xcode project together with the dylib behavior I can probably take a look when time permits.

Comment: @l'L'l That's very kind of you. I have added a sample project.

Comment: I found the issue with the dylib; I'll write up an answer shortly.

Comment: @l'L'l Great, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my earlier comment as mentioned the name of the `dylib` in the error message differs (`3.2` vs. `3.2.0`) from that of the one you are actually using. Since the `dylib` is already built and you are including it this way in your project that's an indicator an existing `rpath` or `id` already exists.

**Using `otool`:**

```
$ otool -l libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib
...
 Load command 3
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name @rpath/libopencv_core.3.2.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Wed Dec 31 17:00:01 1969
      current version 3.2.0
compatibility version 3.2.0
...
 Load command 16
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path /usr/local/lib (offset 12)
```

Two things can be observed here; the first being the `LC_ID_DYLIB` which confirms the discrepancy, and secondly,  the `LC_RPATH` (rpath) which is present is set to indicate the library location is `/usr/local/lib`. Since you are including the lib with your app it should be updated.

**Update the library (the one included in your app):**

```
$ install_name_tool -id @rpath/libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib
```

Updates the `LC_ID_DYLIB`.

```
$ install_name_tool -add_rpath "@executable/../Frameworks" libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib
```

Adds the correct `LC_RPATH`.

```
$ install_name_tool -delete_rpath "/usr/local/lib" libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib
```

Removes the `rpath` `/usr/local/lib` from the library. To verify run `otool -l` again:

```
...
 Load command 3
          cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name @rpath/libopencv_core.3.2.0.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 1 Wed Dec 31 17:00:01 1969
      current version 3.2.0
compatibility version 3.2.0
...
 Load command 17
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @executable/../Frameworks (offset 12)
```

Now you should be able to include the `dylib` in a standalone app and it's path should be set correctly; the updated `dylib` is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78dfq412n61enqw/libopencv_dylib.zip?dl=0). After updating the library the app opens without issue.

**Notes:** In your question you are importing `libopencv_core3.2.0.dylib`, although the error states `libopencv_imgproc.3.2.dylib`, but I assume it's another `dylib` which suffers a similar issue, so this can certainly be applied to others. The `rpath` you had originally set in Xcode was correct

[image]

although since libraries allow multiple `rpaths` to exist and `/usr/local/bin` already is present it's using that location first, in addition to the wrong name.

Comment: Excellent. I was not aware of these internals, but now I see where the problem originates from. The other lib(s) need similar adjustments. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Thank you very much for the (unexpected) bounty Thomas! It really made my day, cheers! :)

Comment: You made my day :-)